# Multiple Correspondence Analysis as PCA

Tags: r, pca, factor-analysis, correspondence-analysis

The book "Multiple Factor Analysis by Example Using R" states that MCA can be thought as an unstandardized PCA of the transformed Complete Disjunctive Table (basically an indicator matrix).

The transformation is such that an element of the table say $y_{i,k}$ is transformed as follows:

$$
x_{i,k} = \frac{y_{i,k}}{p_k} - 1
$$

The problem is that the results I found are completely different from standard MCA applied to the indicator matrix or the Burt table.

I don't know if I am missing something...

The minimum code for the computation:

```
library(factoextra)

dat <- read.table("wg93.txt", header = TRUE, colClasses = "factor")

I <- dim(dat)[1]

# Compute the indicator matrix
lev.n <- unlist(lapply(dat, nlevels))
n <- cumsum(lev.n)
J.t <- sum(lev.n)
Q.t <- dim(dat)[2]
Z <- matrix(0, nrow = I, ncol = J.t)
newdat <- lapply(dat, as.numeric)
offset <- (c(0, n[-length(n)]))
for (i in 1:Q.t){
    Z[1:I + (I * (offset[i] + newdat[[i]] - 1))] <- 1
}
fn <- rep(names(dat), unlist(lapply(dat, nlevels)))
ln <- unlist(lapply(dat, levels))
dimnames(Z)[[2]] <- paste(fn, ln, sep = "")
dimnames(Z)[[1]] <- as.character(1:I)

# Evaluate pk
p <- apply(Z, 2,sum) / I

# Compute CDT transformation
Y <- (Z %*% diag(1/p)) - 1

res.pca <- prcomp(Y, scale = FALSE)
get_eigenvalue(res.pca)
```

The sample data can be found here https://www.ogi-nic.net/CARME-N/download/wg93.txt

Comment: The same information is stated on the Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_correspondence_analysis